# Is there a way to do collaborative learning with h2o.ai (flow)?

Tags: h2o

Relatively new to ML and `h2o`. Is there a way to do collaborative learning/training with `h2o`? Would prefer a way that uses the `flow UI`, else woud be using python.

My use case is that there would be new feature samples x=[a, b, c, d] periodically coming into a system where an `h2o` algorithm (say, running from a java program using a `MOJO`) assigns a binary class that users should be able to manually reclassify as either good(0) or bad(1), at which point these samples (with their newly assigned responses) get sent back to theh h2o algorithm to be used to further train it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FLOW UI is great for prototyping something very quick with H2O without writing a single like of code. You can ingest the data, build desired model and the evaluate the results. Unfortunately FLOW UI is can not be extended for the reason you asked, and FLOW is limited for that reason.

For collaborative learning you can write your whole application directly in python or R and it will work as expected.

Comment: Is there a way to do continual training in h2o with python? Ie. save the trained state of an algorithm and continue training it later? I have only ever used `flow UI` and `MOJOs` up to this point and can't find documentation on how to set up continual training with the h2o programming APIs. Thanks

Comment: You really have to look at the python API to built it from scratch. There are APIs available to perform everything needed however you will have to put them together for your task.